# For Loop with indexed data

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, indexing

the question may look trivial to you, but it really is giving me a hard time. I have data in several data.frame() that are indexed in this format: Patient1, Patient2, Patient3, ...

So my intent is to use a for loop to adress the same steps to all of these data.frames(), like this:

```
Pat <- c (1:ncol(a))

for (i in Pat) {
  Observedi <- Pati
  Amount <- Drug [Drug$a == i, ]
  i+1
}
```

This is working for Filtering the Amount variable, but not for the first line. What am I missing? Do I need to use i+1 or is R counting automatically?

Regards,
CG

Edited for clarification purposes:

```
Patient1 <- data.frame(1:10, 11:20, 21:30)
Patient2 <- data.frame(1:10, 21:30, 41:50)

nPat <- 1:2

for (i in nPat)
{Observed[i] <- Patient[i]

 }
```

I want to have (in this case) two Observed-data.frames and these should have the same index as the Patient-data.frames

But it is not working since the console states that the object "patient" could not be found. So I think it is not recognizing i as a counter variable, but I dont know to code this any better. Do you have any hints?

Kind regards

Comment: please create a reproducible example

Comment: It seems Pati should be Pat[i] instead? In what sense it is not working, please make clear what the issue is. How is Observedi related to the rest of the loop code? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Showing the structure of your data would be useful. Ah, and you don't need to increment i at the end of the loop. The for() already takes care of it. That's what probably is causing your for() to skip rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are using square brackets to try to refer to your data frames. When you do `Patient[1]`, R interprets this as "the first element of an object called `Patient`". It doesn't realise you want the *whole* of an object called `Patient1`. Similarly, it doesn't convert `Pati` to `Pat1`.

Therefore, in your loop, when you do `Patient[i]`, R throws an error because there is no object called `Patient`.

There are a few ways around this problem, but the easiest would be to get all your data frames into a list. That way you can still select individual data frames, you can iterate over them, and even join them together if you want.

If your data frames are all called `Patient1`, `Patient2`, etc., then this code will put copies of them into a list called `Observed`:

```r
df_names <- grep("Patient(\\d)+", ls(), value = TRUE)
Observed <- lapply(df_names, get)
names(Observed) <- df_names
```

So now you have a list of data frames called `Observed`, which looks like this:

```
Observed
#> $Patient1
#>     a  b  c
#> 1   1 11 21
#> 2   2 12 22
#> 3   3 13 23
#> 4   4 14 24
#> 5   5 15 25
#> 6   6 16 26
#> 7   7 17 27
#> 8   8 18 28
#> 9   9 19 29
#> 10 10 20 30
#> 
#> $Patient2
#>     a  b  c
#> 1   1 21 41
#> 2   2 22 42
#> 3   3 23 43
#> 4   4 24 44
#> 5   5 25 45
#> 6   6 26 46
#> 7   7 27 47
#> 8   8 28 48
#> 9   9 29 49
#> 10 10 30 50
```

You can access each patient data frame like this:

```
Observed$Patient1
#>     a  b  c
#> 1   1 11 21
#> 2   2 12 22
#> 3   3 13 23
#> 4   4 14 24
#> 5   5 15 25
#> 6   6 16 26
#> 7   7 17 27
#> 8   8 18 28
#> 9   9 19 29
#> 10 10 20 30
```

If you want to join them all into one big data frame, you can do:

```
do.call("rbind", Observed)
#>              a  b  c
#> Patient1.1   1 11 21
#> Patient1.2   2 12 22
#> Patient1.3   3 13 23
#> Patient1.4   4 14 24
#> Patient1.5   5 15 25
#> Patient1.6   6 16 26
#> Patient1.7   7 17 27
#> Patient1.8   8 18 28
#> Patient1.9   9 19 29
#> Patient1.10 10 20 30
#> Patient2.1   1 21 41
#> Patient2.2   2 22 42
#> Patient2.3   3 23 43
#> Patient2.4   4 24 44
#> Patient2.5   5 25 45
#> Patient2.6   6 26 46
#> Patient2.7   7 27 47
#> Patient2.8   8 28 48
#> Patient2.9   9 29 49
#> Patient2.10 10 30 50
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, that helped a lot. So now I am able to call the object i of that list. If I now execute the for-loop, it gives this error: "in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = NULL) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns" What is this about?

Comment: @ClaireGrube but you don't need the loop, since you have copies of all the data frames stored already. If you really need copies of each data frame called `Observed1`,  `Observed2` etc, then you can do `for(i in seq_along(Observed)) assign(paste0("Observed", i), Observed[[i]])` but it's not clear why you need this.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I ll try to get that done now. Helped me a lot!